# JSON - Find the length of objects

Tags: javascript, json

HI,

I'm having a JSON parsed return object set.

```
{
  "word":[
      "offered",
      "postings"
  ],

  "annotation":[
      ["offered highlighted","this is also given as annotation","This annotation has been added here currently","offering new annotation points","\"offered\" is in the sense of languages"],
      ["my postings","this is new annotation for postings.","my postings","this is posting annotation.... Working for the feature of the annotation."]
  ],

  "user":[
  ["","","vinoth","Anonymous","Vinoth"],
  ["Anonymous","vinoth","Anonymous","Arputharaj"]
  ],

  "id":[
  ["58","60","61","63","68"],
  ["32","57","59","62"]
  ],

  "comment":
  {
    "id58":["first comment","This is a old comment for this annotation","Next level of commenting.","Fourth comment to this annotation","testing"],
    "id61":["this is an old annotation.\r\nMy comment is very bad about this.","Second comment to this annotation"],
    "id57":["I want to add one more comment to this"]
    },

    "commentUser":{
      "id58":["vinoth","Anonymous","Vinothkumar","Vinothkumar","vinoth"],
      "id61":["Anonymous","Commentor"],
      "id57":["vinoth"]
      }
  }
```

I want to know about the length of each object and array.

I've used `.length` to get the length of `annotation[0].length`. I'm getting the expected result i.e.: 5. The same is to "user" & "id".

But I'm not getting the lengths of "word", "id58", "id61", etc...
Also I want to know about the length of the `comment` & `commentUser`.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value for the key `word` in your example (let's call it `obj`) is an array, so `obj.word.length` should be 2.

The value for `comment` and `commentUser` is an object, which does not have length per se, so you'll need to count them yourself:

```
var length=0;
for(var dummy in obj.comment) length++;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is working for "comment" & "commentUSer". But "myObj.word.length" is returning "undefined"
(myObj is my object).

Comment: @Vinothkumar Arputharaj - assuming `myObj` has the definition given in your sample code, then `myObj.word` is an array of length 2. If you find that `myObj.word.length` is `undefined` then some part of your description of the situation is wrong. Why not set a breakpoint in your browser and examine the data? You can do this in Firefox with Firebug, or with the built-in debuggers of IE 8 and Chrome.

Comment: However, I'm able to get the length of ** myObj.word.length ** by counting using for loop.

Answer (score 7):

To count the number of properties an object has, you need to loop through the properties but remember to use the `hasOwnProperty` function:

```
var count = 0;
for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

If you forget to do that, you will be looping through inherited properties. If you (or some library) has assigned a function to the prototype of `Object`, then all objects will seem to have that property, and thus will seem one item "longer" than they intrinsically are.

To avoid the need to remember this, consider using jQuery's `each` instead:

```
var count = 0;
$.each(obj, function(k, v) { count++; });
```

**UPDATE** With current browsers:

```
Object.keys(someObj).length
```