# Calulating length in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Below is my object in JavaScript, how can i calculate the length of it.

```
var treeObj = {
            1: ['96636736','10'],
            2 : ['96636734','20'],
            3 : ['96636731','45']
              };
```

**`treeObj .length`** is not working. any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is the length of the object? What should be printed for this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(treeObj).length;  // 3
```

`getOwnPropertyNames` returns array of properties of `treeObj` whose `length` can be checked.

Comment: It should be noted that you should avoid this method if you are targeting older browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of properties an object has, you need to loop through the properties but remember to use the hasOwnProperty function:

```
var count = 0;
for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

If you forget to do that, you will be looping through inherited properties. If you (or some library) has assigned a function to the prototype of Object, then all objects will seem to have that property, and thus will seem one item "longer" than they intrinsically are.

consider using jQuery's each instead:

```
var count = 0;
$.each(obj, function(k, v) { count++; });
```

OR simply,

```
 for (var p in obj) 
            count++;
```

UPDATE With current browsers:

```
Object.keys(someObj).length
```

Refer [Old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385820/json-find-the-length-of-objects)

Comment: jQuery's `$.each()` doesn't include a `.hasOwnProperty` check. Not sure how jQuery relates to this question in the first place.

Comment: Nope, of course `$.each` doesn't include a `.hasOwnProperty`  is a just another example to get the count.

Comment: *"To avoid the need to remember this..."* sounded like you're suggesting that it does. If not, then he might as well do `for (var p in obj) count++;` since it's shorter and faster.

Comment: yeah, it is. Let me edit the answer. Thanks